# SQL Updated since last visit column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm working with SQL Server and I'm pretty new to SQL in general, so if this is a very trivial question, please bear with me.

I have a table in a database with a datetime field representing some timestamp. When extracting the table via a SELECT statement, I would like to have a column of True/False representing whether or not the row has been updated since some given time.

I've tried something like:

```
"SELECT val1, val2, FORMAT(LastTimestamp > " + GivenTime + ", 'True/False')" +
"FROM table"
```

I've gotten something similar to work on the w3 online query tester, but I think that may be in MySQL and I was unable to test datetimes. The database right now seems to complain about the > symbol.

Anyone know the proper query string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like:

```
select val1, val2, 
case when LastTimestamp > '20100720' then 'True' else 'False' end as [True/False] 
from Table
```

Note that in the above I've used a date literal which breaks down into 'yyyymmdd'

Comment: I get the following errors from this:
Error in SELECT clause: expression near '>'.
Error in SELECT clause: expression near 'FROM'.
Missing FROM clause.
Unable to parse query text.

Comment: @user - Looking at your original query I think you're putting it in quotes. That might explain why there is a missing FROM near FROM at least! You don't need to do that. as YellowFrog has written it above should work fine.

Comment: Agreed, YellowFrog's query looks fine

Comment: Hey, you guys, it's yellowFOG. YellowFROG, sheesh: what a stupid name.